# How can I make an image span rows in bootstrap 3.2?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to figure out how to get an image/map or whatever, in this case a map, displayed to the right side of my form.

This image shows what I want it to look like. It will be a dynamically generated Google map however.

[image: This is what I would like to end up with]

Here is my current code for the form itself via bootply.

[Bootply Example](http://www.bootply.com/tyQw78oJnu)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add another wrapper row and column inside your container.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8">
        <!-- Your Form Here-->
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <!-- Your Image here-->
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This wasn't directly the fix for me, but it pushed me in the right direction and got it working, so Thanks!